# Nginx rewrite doesn't work with typical extensions

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have a nginx rewrite location conf like this

```
location /playernew {
    error_log /home/heyka/rewrite-error.log debug;
    if ($request_filename ~ /playernew/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.+)){
      rewrite /playernew/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.+) /playernew/$2 break;
    }
```

For e.g. url `.com/playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss` works. Notice `.csss` extension.

And in log I have:

```
2019/09/09 17:35:41 [notice] 28519#0: *103 "/playernew/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.+)" matches "/home/website/www/playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss", client: ip, server: nocache.website.com, request: "GET /playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss HTTP/1.1", host: "nocache.website.com"
2019/09/09 17:35:41 [notice] 28519#0: *103 "/playernew/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.+)" matches "/playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss", client: ip, server: nocache.website.com, request: "GET /playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss HTTP/1.1", host: "nocache.website.com"
2019/09/09 17:35:41 [notice] 28519#0: *103 rewritten data: "/playernew/assets/css/style.csss", args: "", client: ip, server: nocache.website.com, request: "GET /playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss HTTP/1.1", host: "nocache.website.com"
2019/09/09 17:35:41 [error] 28519#0: *103 open() "/home/website/www/playernew/assets/css/style.csss" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ip, server: nocache.website.com, request: "GET /playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.csss HTTP/1.1", host: "nocache.website.com"
```

But...

When I hit the `.com/playernew/wydra/assets/css/style.css`. Notice `.css`... Doesn't work completly. Nothing in logs. Nothing. Like rewrite command never existed.

Even with config like...

```
location /playernew {
    error_log /home/arek/rewrite-error.log debug;
    rewrite style.css / break;
```

the same :/

Why? What is going on?

Why `.csss` works but `.css` doesn't. And the same with other regular extensions.

Again -> hitting `/playernew/wydra/setup/index.phpp` generates log and rewrite works.

But hitting `/playernew/wydra/setup/index.php`... no log + doesn't work.

For me it has problem with any typical extension

Comment: Do you have a regular expression `location` block that matches URIs ending with `.css`? For example, something like: `location ~ \.(css|js)$ { ... }`

Comment: Your config is kind of weird. `if` is bad, especially inside locations. Why don't you just put `rewrite /playernew/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/(.+) /playernew/$2 last;` in `server` context? (without any location)

Comment: @DanilaVershinin will try

Comment: @RichardSmith I had and there was still the same problem

Comment: Nginx [chooses one location to process a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#simple_php_site_configuration). A matching regular expression `location` will take precedence over your `location /playernew` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith this location was at the top. Just below the `location / {
        index   index.html index.php;
    }`